# Import TNS Modules in the same typescript file of the angular web app

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Nativescript Angular is well known for its code sharing properties. I am trying to simplify my design by using only 1 typescript file instead of splitting into the `.ts` and the `.tns.ts` file.

I was trying to `import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";` in the `.ts`. When running on Android, the code works flawlessly, but if I `ng serve` for the web app, it says `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/page'`.

The reason why I wanted to import the page module is because of setting the action bar properties

```
constructor(private page: Page) { 

  if (isAndroid) {
    console.log("This is Android");
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
  }
}
```

I was hoping to import the `tns-core-modules/ui/page` and some other tns-core-modules in the same file as the angular web app. Is it possible to do so? Or is it a must to split into the `.ts` and the `.tns.ts` files?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with platform specific ts files, one for web and one for tns, `Page` won't be valid while running inside a browser (ng serve).

If you prefer to reuse most of your code, try writting a common / base ts component, extend platform specific ts files from the common / base ts component, inject `Page` only within the tns specific ts file.